# Visual Studio won't load the website project if homepage is not working?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

Visual Studio is set to use IIS Server for running the website. Now, the homepage has some problem, so my project simply won't load in Visual Studio!

It gives the following error:

**C:...\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProjectName\ProjectName\ProjectName.csproj : error  : The Web Application Project ProjectName is configured to use IIS. The Web server 'http://10.1.1.1/' could not be found.**

How to fix something like that when the project wont even open up?! But anyway, I guessed the error in homepage and got rid of it using notepad, but it still kept getting stuck on the same error (even though it is non-existent now), so I cleared the bin folder hoping it would force things to recompile, and now it's giving me this:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ProjectName.ProjectName'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ProjectName.ProjectName" Language="C#" %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It could be so many things... I'll toss out a blanket statement that will fix your problem.  Create a new website in VS and manually add all the existing files from your old website.

Comment: it's not so many things, it's breaking primarily because home page is broken and returning 500. And I wanted to know if there is a way to tell Visual Studio to load up the project even if the url is broken.